# Solving $a^{x} = 10^{2x + 1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So here is the problem:

Solved for a in terms of x:
$$a^{x} = 10^{2x + 1}$$

I tried:
$\displaystyle x \cdot \log(a) = (2x+1) \cdot \log\;10 $

$\displaystyle \frac{x}{2x + 1} = \frac{\log\;10} {\log\;a} $

But this is not going in the right direction, the answer according to the book is:
$$ \frac{1} {\log\;a - 2} $$

*Excuse the 'power' tag for this question, there is no logarithm tag*

Comment: +1: For showing the effort you have put into the question.

Comment: You are, in fact, going in the right direction.  Keep going.

Comment: Can you solve the equation $$ax=b(2x+1)$$ for $x$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: The answer is using $\log_{10}$.

Comment: so I get to $ x = \frac{2x + 1}{log a} $  Please excuse my utter stupidity if I am unable to convert this into the answer! =S

Comment: @giddy: Can you solve $3x = 2x + 1$? What about $100x = 2x + 1$?

Comment: (I can increase the teX font size)

Comment: @giddy: I have edited the answer to increase the font size. You can either use `\displaystyle` or use two dollar signs.

Comment: @Moron so first equation $$ (3x-2x=1) x = 1 $$ and the second $$ x = \frac {1}{98} $$ Correct? Dont see how it related to simplifying this==> $$ x = \frac {2x + 1}{log a} $$

Comment: Just after taking log what did you get?

Comment: in which equation? my problem? Thats what I get right, up here?

Comment: @giddy: Don't you get log(a). x = 2x + 1? Is this not similar to 3x = 2x+1 or 100x = 2x +1? How did you solve those?

Comment: @giddy, Don't divide yet! Get all the terms with an $x$ on the left hand side, and all the terms without an $x$ on the right hand side, and *then* you divide.

Comment: ...and a final hint: $ax-bx=(a-b)x$

Comment: GOT IT... ugh feel like really kicking myself in the arse... log(a). x = 2x + 1 ==> 2x - xloga = 1 ==> x(2 - log a) = 1 >> x = 1/2-log a

Comment: thank you for the annoying hints making me FIND my own answer... I know it took more **time** ...I wish I could see through problems like this but its mostly my frustration and anxiety i think thats getting in the way!!

Comment: oopsy... i made a sign mistake in the previous comment!

Comment: @giddy: Don't worry, it will become easier once you are more familiar.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**$\ $  Putting $\rm\ a = 10^{\:b}\ $ yields $\rm\ x = 1/(b - 2)$

Comment: you're using ln and e, not log base 10? Also, this makes me realize   $$ x = \frac{2x + 1}{log a} $$ that is the answer.. so i could've left it at that since the question is only solve not show that this equals that?

Comment: The point of the hint is to completely avoid logs!

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Maybe you can find useful to look at [Logarithm - Change of base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base), after solving your equation $\displaystyle \frac{x}{2x+1}=\frac{\text{log} 10}{\text{log}\thinspace a}$. You should finish with something like $x = \displaystyle \frac{1}{\frac{\displaystyle \text{log} \thinspace a}{\displaystyle \text{log} 10}-2}$

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So here is wat I got...
\begin{align*}
a^x &= 10^{2x}+1\\
x\log(a) &= 2x\log(10) + \log(10)\\
x\log(a) - 2x\log(10) &= \log (10)\\
x(\log(a)-2\log10) &= \log (10)\\
x &= (\log10) / (\log(a) - 2\log10)\\
x &= (1) / (\log(a) - 2)\\
\end{align*}